# Access pods frameworks in Xcode workspace (CocoaPods in Xcode 6)

Tags: xcode, xcode6, cocoapods, xcode6.1

I can't access frameworks added in my Podfile in my workspace. This is happening only in new projects in Xcode 6 with Objective-C

There weren't any errors when running `pod install` and there aren't any errors in the project.

Can you suggest me how to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems its a problem with when you run CocoaPods on Xcode 6 on Yosemite.

I found the solution here. http://iosnow.net/?p=36

Everything is working good now.